# Pop up screen on libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, screen

Hi I want to make a pause and credits screen for an android game with libgdx the idea I have is creating a new screen like a popup that pauses the background screen and then, I can render the screen I want to show. Please give me some info or ideas for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introduce a state variable. When the state is paused and not running draw a scene2d stage with the elements of your pause screen. Unpausing sets the state back to running, which then starts rendering and updating your game screen.

The overlay or popup effect can be achieved through an image.

So in short: use a switch case statement on the game state in your update and render methods.